# How do I display a collection of UserControls in html.ascx?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, ascx

I have created a list of user controls that use the same interface to populate the data fields in each card depending on what the data object's label is. The problem I am running into is I don't know how to display this collection of objects in the html page.

```
var compiledList = new List<ICard>();
foreach (DataResult entityObject in entityList)
{
    switch (entityObject.Label)
    {
        case "Employee":
            //create control as ICard
            ICard usrControl = new empsumCardUserControl(entityObject) as ICard;
            ((ICard)usrControl).Populate();
            compiledList.Add(usrControl);
            break;
    }
}
```

How do I display the compiledList in a formatted section of my HTML page?

Comment: So `compiledList` is a collection of UserControls and you want to display all of them on one .aspx page?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Think of it as a bunch of small box search stubs that need to be displayed together on a page. For example: you are searching for vehicles that are red and a bunch of search results come back including a stub for cars (unique user control), trucks (unique user control), and mopeds (unique user control). They would be displayed in some sort of container on the web page.

Comment: Have you tried a `asp:Repeater` control?

Comment: How would I attach the Repeater control to the compiledList?

Comment: You think of it the wrong way. The Repeater is a control on the aspx page and you need to define an ItemTemplate for it. This can be your CustomControl. You then only need to fill it with data.

Comment: There are 3 different custom controls....so the item template cant just be one control.

Comment: In your code you are only creating objects of type `ICard`. This is only one type. If you did not show all relevant code, then this is all obsolete. Then you need 3 Reapter controls.

Comment: ICard is an interface. "empsumCardUserControl" is the user control. I want a layer of abstraction so that when I add more user controls I do not need to keep adding repeater controls or any other kind of control.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use a place holder in the HTML and create an instance of the user control to load it in the code behind, and then add it to the placeholder.

```
case "Employee":    
     empsumCardUserControl ec = (empsumCardUserControl)LoadControl("~/View/empsumCardUserControl.ascx");
     ((ICard)ec).Populate(entityObject);
     PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ec);
     break;
```